# What's the meaning of "run over"?

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of "run over" in the following passage?

> Similar observations concerning the pitfalls associated with
>   undertaking accounting research that operates on either center-margin
>   have been offered before, and in much more convincing detail, by both
>   mainstream (Merchant, 2008) and critical (Spence, 2009; Tinker,
>   Lehman, & Neimark, 1991) accounting researchers. Mentioning them here
>   is not intended to engender any academic sympathy. Given that
>   quantitative SEA research is often considered by both mainstream and
>   critical groups to operate in the ‘‘middle of the road’’, it comes as
>   little surprise that a non-mainstream quantitative SEA project leads
>   to either a ‘‘rock’’ or a ‘‘hard place’’, or at some point in the
>   publication process, is ‘‘run over’’ from either direction.

Comment: It's the hit-by-a-car-etc sense, used metaphorically (as part of an extended / whimsically mixed metaphor) here. Flattened.

Comment: It comes from the variously worded adage: If you stay in the middle of the road, you're likely to get run over.  http://mobile.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/ambrosebie121123.html   Metaphorically, this means it's better to choose a "side" (a scientific theory, a political viewpoint, whatever) rather than trying to compromise by steering a "middle" course.

Comment: The tangle of metaphors for danger here (pitfall, rock, hard place) and the ambiguity of what it means to be run over from the direction of a rock or from the direction of a hard place make this paragraph harder to comprehend than it ought to be. But Both Edwin Ashworth and Brian Hitchcock nicely explain what the author was trying to say.